# Singularity issue in censReg

Tags: r

I was running a TOBIT regresion on my data. My data consists of 3 variables, spanning over 5 years, with 185 observations in total. Readers can see the first few lines of my data as below:

```
TTrevenue       Donation1   Year
50668000        4331        2011
12351800        33500       2011
848360909       96000       2011
10153384        60800       2011
16234000        8000        2011
12232679        34980       2011
4172600         8000        2011
3588000         0           2011
11686159        11140.10819 2011
1019275000      278000      2011
513046484       50227.261   2011
10833839        21578.75559 2011
25588057        500         2011
```

The minimum value of "Donation1" is 0, and there is no maximum value for "Donation1". Therefore, the variable "Donation1" is left censored. Also, the variable "Year" is a factor.

I converted this dataset into pdata format, using pdata command.

```
> class(dat.panel)
[1] "pdata.frame" "data.frame"
```

Here is my TOBIT regression model. I am predicting Donation using TTrevenue over 5 year (2011 to 2015)

```
reg1 <- censReg(Donation1 ~ TTrevenue, data = dat.panel)
```

I encountered the following error when I run "reg1".

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.18069e-21
```

Why would my model be singular if there is only one predicting variable? Did I set up my regression model incorrectly?

I appreciate any comments. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
When I changed my explanatory variable, the error message went away, but I had the following output.

```
Call:
censReg(formula = Donation1 ~ log(ROE), data = dat.panel)

Observations:
         Total  Left-censored     Uncensored Right-censored 
           185              1            184              0 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. error t value Pr(> t)
(Intercept) 63464.71        Inf       0       1
log(ROE)    -5785.16        Inf       0       1
logSigmaMu      -Inf        Inf      NA      NA
logSigmaNu     11.47        Inf       0       1

Newton-Raphson maximisation, 8 iterations
Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit
Log-likelihood: -2372.245 on 4 Df
```

There was only 1 observation that is left-censored. Is that one of the reasons why my model doesn't fit well?

Comment: Generally singularity is due to the covariate structure. Presenting only the "first few lines" is not likely to be particularly informative, and that is especially so when the print representation is the only information on offer.

Comment: Surprisingly, when I change my explanatory variable, the regression model works. Please have a look of my updates above.

Comment: Not at all surprising. Predictable. You have not offered any useful information about the nature of your predictor variables. The statement about why the "Donation1" variable is left-censored appears wrong to me. I think you need a serious review of your methods and your data by a competent statistician.